# Why are the default attributes in my model returning undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have defined my model and it's default variables; yet, whenever I try to use any of these variables inside model itself, their values are set to 'undefined'.

```
    JAWeatherWatch.module('Cities', function(Cities, JAWeatherWatch, Backbone, Marionette){

        /*  Cities
        *   This model is used to model the datat retued by the open weather api 
        *   for each individual city in jamaica
        */
        Cities.City = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults:{
                // stores my api key as well the required query string to add to the request
                apiKey: '&APPID=84cb7efaf4ac2947aa6381637904ee5e',
                country:'jamaica',
                parishName: false
            }, 
            url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + this.parishName  + "," + this.country + this.apiKey,
            initialize: function(){

                console.log(this.country); // => 'undefined'

                // todo: get json data from api
            }
        });


    });


    var test = new JAWeatherWatch.Cities.City({parishName:'kingston'});
    console.log(test.get('country')) // => 'jamaica'
```

The strange thing is that they behave as expected (i.e.return the correct values) after the model is instantiated. I am at a total loss as to why this is the case

Comment: yeap, because `this.country` is really undefined use `this.get('country')`

Comment: I tried that and got the following error : 'TypeError: this.get is not a function'

Answer (score 2):

You cant use `this.country`, since backbone stores the models' attributes in a key called `attributes` within the model. So they could be accessed in theory using this.attributes.country. But please don't do that. A models attributes should be accessed using `model.get()`

So in your case that would be `this.get( "country" )`

Refer to the Backbone documentation, if you want to know more. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get

Comment: Solved the issue. Concatenated the strings using this.get in a separate function.